# What pseuorandom number generator does Amazon Redshift use for RANDOM?

Tags: postgresql, random, amazon-redshift

The documentation for Amazon Redshift's [RANDOM function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RANDOM.html) does not indicate which pseudorandom number generator is used.

The documentation for Amazon Redshift's [SET function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html) indicates the ability to set a seed between 0 and 1, which is multiplied by 2^(31)-1.

While this helps verify the precision of values for the output (already known to be DOUBLE PRECISION by the RANDOM function documentation), I have been unable to locate anywhere in the documentation nor an online search precisely which [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) is being used.

Comment: I can't speak for redshift specifically, but postgres (from which redshift was forked about 15 years ago) uses the system-provided random number generator. Since redshift is closed source, and runs on inaccessible systems, I strongly suspect that you need to talk to Amazon to get an accurate answer.

Comment: @jmelesky Thanks, it seems then that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816114/quality-of-postgresqls-random-function is probably the closest publicly available answer.