# Naming each row in the table with a random 2 word string

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to choose a simple naming conventions to the table in my database.

It means I have to name each row with a random 2 word string.

For example

ID NAME

1  ROMEL SUMPI

2  BORMI SUIEMOD

and so on,,,,,,,,,

It means each NAME column should have a Unique name.....

How can I do this in PHP which uses postgreSQL DB....

Thank you in advance,,.,,,,

Comment: Define "random". Your examples don't look "random" at all.

Comment: Hi,, I am just trying to insert random names in the NAME column of my postgreSQL table,,, Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: Again: Define "random". Would "fjdskjfejgiowj" be an appropriate name? How about "0000001572"?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you actually mean "arbitrary" unique names. Simple way could be:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name)
SELECT g, 'name'::text || g || ' surname' || g
FROM   generate_series(1, 1000) g;
```

.. to generate 1000 distinct names - not random at all, but unique.

To generate 100 names consisting of two words with 3 - 10 random letters from A-Z:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name)
SELECT g%100
      ,left(string_agg(chr(65 + (random() * 25)::int), ''), 3 + (random() * 7)::int)
       || ' ' ||
       left(string_agg(chr(65 + (random() * 25)::int), ''), 3 + (random() * 7)::int)
FROM   generate_series(1, 1000) g
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

ASCII code of 'A' is 65, the one of 'Z' is 90. Fortunately, the range between spans the basic upper case alphabet. You can find out with the [`ascii()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), which is the reverse of [`chr()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT ascii('A')
```

The second method doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but duplicates are extremely unlikely with just a few hundred names. Eliminating possible duplicates is trivial. Add another `SELECT` layer where you `GROUP BY name` and pick `min(id)`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-random-string-in-postgresql for the random string aspect.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Didn't you also implement a random generator in C some time ago? I seem to remember a posting on DBA?

Comment: Yes, but it generates random `bytea` not constrained `text` values. It'd be trivial to alter, but I don't think there's much point; the problem I was trying to solve was generating *lots* of *big* random data. It's here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22512/how-can-i-generate-a-random-bytea . I wouldn't use a C extension for a job as simple as the one this question is about.

Comment: @CraigRinger: No, of course not. Not for this trivial case. But I remember it was good stuff - worth mentioning in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want a pair of randomly-selected *words* from a *dictionary*. It's kind of hard to tell given the lack of clarity of the question.

### RANDOM DICTIONARY WORDS

The best way to pick random dictionary words is probably at the PHP end by using a pass-phrase generator that does it for you.

You can do it in PostgreSQL using a table `dictionary` with one `word` per row, though:

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2;
```

Performance will be truly awful with a large dictionary. It can be done much faster if the dictionary doesn't change and there's a unique `word_id` with no gaps in the numbering, allowing you to write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_random_word() RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT word FROM dictionary 
WHERE word_id = (
  SELECT width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, (SELECT max(word_id) FROM dictionary))
);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT get_random_word() || ' ' || get_random_word();
```

against a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary(word_id serial primary key, word text UNIQUE NOT NULL);
```

This will only produce consistent results if there are no gaps in the word numbering and if `word_id` is unique or the `PRIMARY KEY`. It *can* produce the same word twice. If you want to avoid that you'll need a recursive CTE or some PL/PgSQL.

### RANDOM GIBBERISH

If you actually want truly random strings, that's already well covered here on Stack Overflow. See [How do you create a random string that's suitable for a session ID in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-random-string-in-postgresql) among others; look at [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgresql+random+string).

To ensure uniqueness, just add a `UNIQUE` constraint. Have your application test to see if a unique_violation was raised when you `INSERT`ed the row, and insert it with a new random ID if a violation occurred. If you like you can automate this with a PL/PgSQL helper procedure, though it'll still be subject to races between concurrent inserts in different transactions.