# How do I shorten and expand a uuid to a 15 or less characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Given a uuid(v4) without dashes, how can I shorten it to a 15 or less than 15 characters string? I should also be able to go back to the original uuid from the 15 characters string.

I am trying to shorten it to send it in a flat file and the file format specifies this field to be a 15 characters alphanumeric field. Given that shortened uuid, I should be able to map it back to the original uuid.

Here is what I tried, but definitely not what I wanted.

```
export function shortenUUID(uuidToShorten: string, length: number) {
  const uuidWithoutDashes = uuidToShorten.replace(/-/g , '');
  const radix = uuidWithoutDashes.length;
  const randomId = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    randomId[i] = uuidWithoutDashes[ 0 | Math.random() * radix];
  }
  return randomId.join('');
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have added what I was doing. That was totally useless and hence didn't add that.

Comment: I _really_ don't understand what you are trying to do. Your algorithm is non-deterministic (i.e., `Math.random()`), so every time you run `shortenUUID()` on _the same input UUID_ you would generate a _different shortened version._ How do you expect to do a _reverse_ mapping that way? What is the _end goal_ of making a shorter UUID? There may be a completely different solution to your problem.

Comment: Exactly my point and that was why I mentioned, what I did was useless.

Comment: @Rama That's fine, and it's good that you posted code, but my question is "what is the _goal_ of shortening a UUID"? Why are you doing it? Is it just a thought exercise? Is it to store it somewhere? Convert it to another base?

Comment: @msanford I am trying to shorten it to send it in a flat file and the file format specifies this field to be a 15 characters alphanumeric field. Given, that shortened uuid, I should be able to map it back to the original uuid.

Comment: @Rama I've updated my answer with a working solution now. I had my math backwards, should have been 16^32, not 32^16. =p

Comment: A v4 UUID contains [121-122 random bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)). If "15 characters alphanumeric field" means it matches `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,15}$/`, you have ~89 bits to work with. [There is no guaranteed way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) of packing 121 bits into 89 bits. If "15 characters alphanumeric field" means something else, you may have more options.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to shorten UUID V4 without making it non-unique/guessable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725745/how-to-shorten-uuid-v4-without-making-it-non-unique-guessable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As AuxTaco pointed out, if you actually mean "alphanumeric" as in it matches "/^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,15}/" (giving the number of bits of 26 + 26 + 10 = 62), then it is really impossible. You can't fit 3 gallons of water in a gallon bucket without losing something. A UUID is 128-bits, so to convert that to a character space of 62, you'd need at least 22 characters (`log[base 62](2^128)` == ~22).

If you are more flexible on your charset and just need it 15 unicode characters you can put in a text document, then my answer will help.

---

Note: First part of this answer, I thought it said length of 16, not 15. The simpler answer won't work. The more complex version below still will.

---

In order to do so, you'd to use some kind of two-way compression algorithm (similar to an algorithm that is used for zipping files).

However, the problem with trying to compress something like a UUID is you'd probably have lots of collisions.

A UUID v4 is 32 characters long (without dashes). It's hexadecimal, so it's character space is 16 characters (`0123456789ABCDEF`)

That gives you a number of possible combinations of `16^32`, approximately  `3.4028237e+38` or `340,282,370,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000`. To make it recoverable after compression, you'd have to make sure you don't have any collisions (i.e., no 2 UUIDs turn into the same value). That's a lot of possible values (which is exactly why we use that many for UUID, the chance of 2 random UUIDs is only 1 out of that number big number).

To crunch that many possibilities to 16 characters, you'd have to have at least as many possible values. With 16 characters, you'd have to have 256 characters (root 16 of that big number, `256^16` == 16^32`). That's assuming you have an algorithm that'd never create a collision.

One way to ensure you never have collisions would be to convert it from a base-16 number to a base-256 number. That would give you a 1-to-1 relation, ensuring no collisions and making it perfectly reversible. Normally, switching bases is easy in JavaScript: `parseInt(someStr, radix).toString(otherRadix)` (e.g., `parseInt('00FF', 16).toString(20)`. Unfortunately, JavaScript only does up to a radix of 36, so we'll have to do the conversion ourselves.

The catch with such a large base is representing it. You could arbitrarily pick 256 different characters, throw them in a string, and use that for a manual conversion. However, I don't think there are 256 different symbols on a standard US keyboard, even if you treat upper and lowercase as different glyphs.

A simpler solution would be to just use arbitrary character codes from `0` to `255` with `String.fromCharCode()`.

Another small catch is if we tried to treat that all as one big number, we'd have issues because it's a really big number and JavaScript can't properly represent it exactly.

Instead of that, since we already have hexadecimal, we can just split it into pairs of decimals, convert those, then spit them out. 32 hexadecimal digits = 16 pairs, so that'll (coincidentally) be perfect. (If you had to solve this for an arbitrary size, you'd have to do some extra math and converting to split the number into pieces, convert, then reassemble.)

```js
const uuid = '1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF';
const letters = uuid.match(/.{2}/g).map(pair => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(pair, 16)));
const str = letters.join('');
console.log(str);
```

Note that there are some random characters in there, because not every char code maps to a "normal" symbol. If what you are sending to can't handle them, you'll instead need to go with the array approach: find 256 characters it can handle, make an array of them, and instead of `String.fromCharCode(num)`, use `charset[num]`.

To convert it back, you would just do the reverse: get the char code, convert to hex, add them together:

```js
const uuid = '1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF';

const compress = uuid => 
  uuid.match(/.{2}/g).map(pair => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(pair, 16))).join('');
  
const expand = str =>
  str.split('').map(letter => ('0' + letter.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-2)).join('');
  
const str = compress(uuid);
const original = expand(str);

console.log(str, original, original.toUpperCase() === uuid.toUpperCase());
```

---

For fun, here is how you could do it for any arbitrary input base and output base.

This code is a bit messy because it is really expanded to make it more self-explanatory, but it basically does what I described above.

Since JavaScript doesn't have an infinite level of precision, if you end up converting a really big number, (one that looks like `2.00000000e+10`), every number not shown after that `e` was essentially chopped off and replaced with a zero. To account for that, you'll have to break it up in some way.

In the code below, there is a "simple" way which doesn't account for this, so only works for smaller strings, and then a proper way which breaks it up. I chose a simple, yet somewhat inefficient, approach of just breaking up the string based on how many digits it gets turned into. This isn't the best way (since math doesn't really work like that), but it does the trick (at the cost of needed a smaller charset).

You could imploy a smarter splitting mechanism if you really needed to keep your charset size to a minimum.

```js
const smallStr = '1234';
const str = '1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF';
const hexCharset = '0123456789ABCDEF'; // could also be an array
const compressedLength = 16;
const maxDigits = 16; // this may be a bit browser specific. You can make it smaller to be safer.

const logBaseN = (num, n) => Math.log(num) / Math.log(n);
const nthRoot = (num, n) => Math.pow(num, 1/n);
const digitsInNumber = num => Math.log(num) * Math.LOG10E + 1 | 0;
const partitionString = (str, numPartitions) => {
  const partsSize = Math.ceil(str.length / numPartitions);
  let partitions = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++) {
    partitions.push(str.substr(i * partsSize, partsSize));
  }
  return partitions;
}

console.log('logBaseN test:', logBaseN(256, 16) === 2);
console.log('nthRoot test:', nthRoot(256, 2) === 16);
console.log('partitionString test:', partitionString('ABCDEFG', 3));

// charset.length should equal radix
const toDecimalFromCharset = (str, charset) => 
    str.split('')
      .reverse()
      .map((char, index) => charset.indexOf(char) * Math.pow(charset.length, index))
      .reduce((sum, num) => (sum + num), 0);
      
const fromDecimalToCharset = (dec, charset) => {
  const radix = charset.length;
  let str = '';
  
  for (let i = Math.ceil(logBaseN(dec + 1, radix)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const part = Math.floor(dec / Math.pow(radix, i));
    dec -= part * Math.pow(radix, i);
    str += charset[part];
  }
  
  return str;
};

console.log('toDecimalFromCharset test 1:', toDecimalFromCharset('01000101', '01') === 69);
console.log('toDecimalFromCharset test 2:', toDecimalFromCharset('FF', hexCharset) === 255);
console.log('fromDecimalToCharset test:', fromDecimalToCharset(255, hexCharset) === 'FF');

const arbitraryCharset = length => new Array(length).fill(1).map((a, i) => String.fromCharCode(i));

// the Math.pow() bit is the possible number of values in the original
const simpleDetermineRadix = (strLength, originalCharsetSize, compressedLength) => nthRoot(Math.pow(originalCharsetSize, strLength), compressedLength);

// the simple ones only work for values that in decimal are so big before lack of precision messes things up
// compressedCharset.length must be >= compressedLength
const simpleCompress = (str, originalCharset, compressedCharset, compressedLength) =>
  fromDecimalToCharset(toDecimalFromCharset(str, originalCharset), compressedCharset);

const simpleExpand = (compressedStr, originalCharset, compressedCharset) =>
  fromDecimalToCharset(toDecimalFromCharset(compressedStr, compressedCharset), originalCharset);

const simpleNeededRadix = simpleDetermineRadix(str.length, hexCharset.length, compressedLength);
const simpleCompressedCharset = arbitraryCharset(simpleNeededRadix);
const simpleCompressed = simpleCompress(str, hexCharset, simpleCompressedCharset, compressedLength);
const simpleExpanded = simpleExpand(simpleCompressed, hexCharset, simpleCompressedCharset);

// Notice, it gets a little confused because of a lack of precision in the really big number.
console.log('Original string:', str, toDecimalFromCharset(str, hexCharset));
console.log('Simple Compressed:', simpleCompressed, toDecimalFromCharset(simpleCompressed, simpleCompressedCharset));
console.log('Simple Expanded:', simpleExpanded, toDecimalFromCharset(simpleExpanded, hexCharset));
console.log('Simple test:', simpleExpanded === str);

// Notice it works fine for smaller strings and/or charsets
const smallCompressed = simpleCompress(smallStr, hexCharset, simpleCompressedCharset, compressedLength);
const smallExpanded = simpleExpand(smallCompressed, hexCharset, simpleCompressedCharset);
console.log('Small string:', smallStr, toDecimalFromCharset(smallStr, hexCharset));
console.log('Small simple compressed:', smallCompressed, toDecimalFromCharset(smallCompressed, simpleCompressedCharset));
console.log('Small expaned:', smallExpanded, toDecimalFromCharset(smallExpanded, hexCharset));
console.log('Small test:', smallExpanded === smallStr);

// these will break the decimal up into smaller numbers with a max length of maxDigits
// it's a bit browser specific where the lack of precision is, so a smaller maxDigits
//  may make it safer
//
// note: charset may need to be a little bit bigger than what determineRadix decides, since we're
//  breaking the string up
// also note: we're breaking the string into parts based on the number of digits in it as a decimal
//  this will actually make each individual parts decimal length smaller, because of how numbers work,
//  but that's okay. If you have a charset just barely big enough because of other constraints, you'll
//  need to make this even more complicated to make sure it's perfect.
const partitionStringForCompress = (str, originalCharset) => {
    const numDigits = digitsInNumber(toDecimalFromCharset(str, originalCharset));
    const numParts = Math.ceil(numDigits / maxDigits);
    return partitionString(str, numParts);
}

const partitionedPartSize = (str, originalCharset) => {
    const parts = partitionStringForCompress(str, originalCharset);
    return Math.floor((compressedLength - parts.length - 1) / parts.length) + 1;
}

const determineRadix = (str, originalCharset, compressedLength) => {
    const parts = partitionStringForCompress(str, originalCharset);
    return Math.ceil(nthRoot(Math.pow(originalCharset.length, parts[0].length), partitionedPartSize(str, originalCharset)));
}

const compress = (str, originalCharset, compressedCharset, compressedLength) => {
    const parts = partitionStringForCompress(str, originalCharset);
    const partSize = partitionedPartSize(str, originalCharset);
    return parts.map(part => simpleCompress(part, originalCharset, compressedCharset, partSize)).join(compressedCharset[compressedCharset.length-1]);
}

const expand = (compressedStr, originalCharset, compressedCharset) =>
    compressedStr.split(compressedCharset[compressedCharset.length-1])
     .map(part => simpleExpand(part, originalCharset, compressedCharset))
     .join('');

const neededRadix = determineRadix(str, hexCharset, compressedLength);
const compressedCharset = arbitraryCharset(neededRadix);
const compressed = compress(str, hexCharset, compressedCharset, compressedLength);
const expanded = expand(compressed, hexCharset, compressedCharset);

console.log('String:', str, toDecimalFromCharset(str, hexCharset));
console.log('Neded radix size:', neededRadix); // bigger than normal because of how we're breaking it up... this could be improved if needed
console.log('Compressed:', compressed);
console.log('Expanded:', expanded);
console.log('Final test:', expanded === str);
```

---

To use the above specifically to answer the question, you would use:

```
const hexCharset = '0123456789ABCDEF';
const compressedCharset = arbitraryCharset(determineRadix(uuid, hexCharset));

// UUID to 15 characters
const compressed = compress(uuid, hexCharset, compressedCharset, 15);

// 15 characters to UUID
const expanded = expanded(compressed, hexCharset, compressedCharset);
```

If there are problematic characters in the arbitrary, you'll have to do something to either filter those out, or hard-code a specific one. Just make sure all of the functions are deterministic (i.e., same result every time).

Comment: There are some problems. This doesn't work for pairs representing a single-digit hex number: try `uuid = '01020304050607080102030405060708';`. If the UUID contains `00`, the system you're sending to may balk at U+0000 NULL in a "15 characters alphanumeric field". And this compresses to 16 characters, not 15.

Comment: Oops, for some reason I thought it said 16. I actually updated my answer with a much more complex approach that works for any arbitrary charset and length, so that could be used for something smaller. You could also filter out any problematic characters. Not sure why you think it wouldn't work for hex representing a single digit, other than they may be goofy characters that some systems may not like. When treating it as relatively arbitrary, it's all essentially just binary.

Comment: Actually, realized why. It doesn't pad the zero when converting back. Fixing that. =p

Comment: If the "15 character alphanumeric field" really does mean `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{15}$/` as you pointed out, then yeah, it's actually impossible. Adding that to my answer.

Comment: And that addresses all the issues I had! Nice!

Comment: This is great! I'd be intrigued to see it reviewed/refined on [CodeReview.se] as well.

Comment: @samanime Thanks a lot for your help with this one. I wasn't expecting it to be so complex, but thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and making it easy to understand.

Comment: @msanford That's a cool idea. Since this was kind of fun, I'm actually writing up a little npm package to do it. For that version, I'm actually using decimal.js so it can handle larger numbers and not have to do the more complex bits that were done to get around JS' lack of precision.