# postgres shuffle random character

Tags: postgresql

I want to shuffle (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890) and get substring from 1 to 6.

I have tried a lot but was not able to find a shuffle function in postgres

```
update tablename 
    set  secureno=substring(shuffle(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890) from 1 for 6)
```

Comment: May be this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-random-string-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

This would do it:

```
SELECT string_agg(c, '')
FROM (SELECT c
      FROM regexp_split_to_table(
              'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',
              ''
           ) c
      ORDER BY random()
      LIMIT 6
     ) AS q;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle a string using this query:

```
select substr('ABCD', i, 1)
from generate_series(1, 4) i
order by random();

 substr 
--------
 B
 C
 A
 D
(4 rows)
```

Use it for your key (with 62 chars), get 6 chars and aggregate to string:

```
select string_agg(ch, '')
from (  
    select substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890', i, 1) ch
    from generate_series(1, 62) i
    order by random()
    limit 6
    ) s
```

You can create a function based on the algorithm if you often need this::

```
create or replace function shuffle(text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select string_agg(ch, '')
    from (
        select substr($1, i, 1) ch
        from generate_series(1, length($1)) i
        order by random()
        ) s
$$;

select left(shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'), 6);
```

Comment: I do not understand. Which duplicates?

Comment: The same character could appear twice in the result. If you truly shuffle the string, that couldn't happen. I don't know if that's important though.

Comment: But in my solution there are no duplicates. Can you see them?