# How to generate a random 6-digit integer that's cryptographically strong?

Tags: postgresql, integer, type-conversion, bytea

We want a function that given an argument that is three bytes of type `bytea` (generated by the function `gen_random_bytes` of the `pgcrypto` extension), the function returns a random 6-digit integer (between 0 & 999999 inclusive). The 6-digit integer should preserve the randomness given by the argument passed to the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to represent a bytea as a single integer in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208945/whats-the-easiest-way-to-represent-a-bytea-as-a-single-integer-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

I might be overcomplicating, but I need to make sure that I have exactly n numeric digits in the string. Repetition of numbers is allowed.

```
SELECT string_agg(shuffle('0123456789')::char, '')
FROM generate_series(1, 6);
```

With the shuffle function provided in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39660410/1385429) that I copied here for convenience

```
create or replace function shuffle(text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select string_agg(ch, '')
    from (
        select substr($1, i, 1) ch
        from generate_series(1, length($1)) i
        order by random()
        ) s
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of 3 bytes, take 6 last chars, prepend `'x'`, convert to bitstring and then to int:

```
select ('x' || right(gen_random_bytes(3)::text, 6))::bit(24)::int;
```

More details are in similar question: [What's the easiest way to represent a bytea as a single integer in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208945/whats-the-easiest-way-to-represent-a-bytea-as-a-single-integer-in-postgresql)

Comment: That may generate something less than 6 digits