# Generate unique random strings in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function to create unique random tokens of variable length. However, I am stumped by the plpgsql syntax. My intention is to create a function which

- Takes a table and column as input
- Generates a random string of a given length, with a given set of characters
- Checks if the string is already in the colum
- If so (and this is expected to be rare), simply generate a new random string.
- Otherwise, return the random string

My current attempt looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_token(_table TEXT, _column TEXT, _length INTEGER) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  alphanum CONSTANT text := 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
  range_head CONSTANT integer := 25;
  range_tail CONSTANT integer := 33;
  random_string text;
BEGIN
  REPEAT
    SELECT substring(alphanum from trunc(random() * range_head + 1)::integer for 1) ||
      array_to_string(array_agg(substring(alphanum from trunc(random() * range_tail + 1)::integer for 1)), '')
      INTO random_string FROM generate_series(1, _length - 1);
  UNTIL random_string NOT IN FORMAT('SELECT %I FROM %I WHERE %I = random_string;', _column, _table, _column)
  END REPEAT;
  RETURN random_string;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, this doesn't work, and gives me a not very helpful error:

> DatabaseError: error 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REPEAT"

I have tried a number of variations, but without knowing what the error in the syntax is I am stumped. Any idea how to fix this function?

Comment: Where in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find `repeat`?

Comment: Do you know what a UUID is, why not just use it? You'll *never* (just about) generate a collision, and it stores in a more compact format and has default operators.

Comment: What is the use case of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `repeat` statement in plpgsql. Use simple [`loop`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_token(_table TEXT, _column TEXT, _length INTEGER) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
  alphanum CONSTANT text := 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789';
  range_head CONSTANT integer := 25;
  range_tail CONSTANT integer := 33;
  random_string text;
  ct int;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT substring(alphanum from trunc(random() * range_head + 1)::integer for 1) ||
      array_to_string(array_agg(substring(alphanum from trunc(random() * range_tail + 1)::integer for 1)), '')
      INTO random_string FROM generate_series(1, _length - 1);
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT count(*) FROM %I WHERE %I = %L', _table, _column, random_string) INTO ct;
    EXIT WHEN ct = 0;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN random_string;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note, `random_string` should be a parameter to `format()`.

Update. According to the accurate hint from Abelisto, this should be faster for a large table:

```
DECLARE
  dup boolean;
...
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM %I WHERE %I = %L)', _table, _column, random_string) INTO dup;
    EXIT WHEN NOT dup;
...
```

Comment: BTW `select count(*) ...` is not the best way to check the existence of the value in the table...

Comment: Thank you very much, I have spent half the day trying to get this to work.

Comment: @klin Simplest for developer but not for the server :o)

Comment: @klin I already upvoted for the your answer so I can not do it twice ;o)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not what you want. When you say, *"checks if the string is already in the column"* you're not referring to something that looks unique, you're referring to something that actually is `UNIQUE`.

[Instead, I would point you over this answer I gave about UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41608000/124486).