# PostgreSQL Generating Alphanumeric ID from Integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57907193/2253323

Or something similar to generate an alphanumeric string from a UNIX timestamp.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION consistent_shuffle(alphabet TEXT, salt TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    SALT_LENGTH INT := length(salt);
    integer INT = 0;
    temp TEXT = '';
    j INT = 0;
    v INT := 0;
    p INT := 0;
    i INT := length(alphabet) - 1;
    output TEXT := alphabet;
BEGIN
    IF salt IS NULL OR length(LTRIM(RTRIM(salt))) = 0 THEN
        RETURN alphabet;
    END IF;
    WHILE i > 0 LOOP
        v := v % SALT_LENGTH;
        integer := ASCII(substr(salt, v + 1, 1));
        p := p + integer;
        j := (integer + v + p) % i;

        temp := substr(output, j + 1, 1);
        output := substr(output, 1, j) || substr(output, i + 1, 1) || substr(output, j + 2);
        output := substr(output, 1, i) || temp || substr(output, i + 2);

        i := i - 1;
        v := v + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_uid(id INT, min_length INT, salt TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    clean_alphabet TEXT := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    curse_chars TEXT := 'csfhuit';
    curse TEXT := curse_chars || UPPER(curse_chars);
    alphabet TEXT := regexp_replace(clean_alphabet, '[' || curse  || ']', '', 'gi');
    shuffle_alphabet TEXT := consistent_shuffle(alphabet, salt);
    char_length INT := length(alphabet);
    output TEXT := '';
BEGIN
    WHILE id != 0 LOOP
        output := output || substr(shuffle_alphabet, (id % char_length) + 1, 1);
        id := trunc(id / char_length);
    END LOOP;
    curse := consistent_shuffle(curse, output || salt);
    output := RPAD(output, min_length, curse);
    RETURN output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

However I get the following error:

```
SELECT generate_uid(ceil(extract(epoch from now())*100000), 8, '20');
```

> [42883] ERROR: function substr(text, bigint, integer) does not exist
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might
>   need to add explicit type casts. Where: PL/pgSQL function
>   demo_generate_uid(bigint,integer,text) line 12 at assignment

I tried changing `id INT` to `BIGINT`. But it doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  There might be a much simpler approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff From an integer to generate an alphanumeric number similar to those of YouTube.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried this?:  output := output || substr(shuffle_alphabet::text, (id % char_length) + 1, 1);

Comment: @strobering Hi. The error appears to be in this line.

Comment: write: shuffle_alphabet::text

Comment: @strobering `[22003] ERROR: integer out of range Where: PL/pgSQL function demo_generate_uid() line 13 during statement block local variable initialization`. I think it's because the unix timestamp is way longer than the `id INT` would allow.

Comment: Ok good,  And why don't you replace with Bigint? I think that it should work now

Comment: @strobering I did. Set `id BIGINT` and get the error in the original question.

Comment: Ok, but if you changed it:  output := output || substr(shuffle_alphabet::text, (id % char_length) + 1, 1);    shouldn't fail now

Comment: It doesn't work. Same error as above. I am passing the following `generate_uid(158800291854464, 8, '20');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Change `int` to `BigInt`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generate_uid(
    id BigInt,
    min_length integer,
    salt text)
...
```

2) Change this line:

```
output := output || substr(shuffle_alphabet, (id % char_length) + 1, 1);
```

to:

```
 output := output || substr(shuffle_alphabet::text, ((id % char_length) + 1)::int, 1);
```

3) And then:

```
SELECT generate_uid(ceil(extract(epoch from now())*100000)::bigint, 8, '20');
```

return:

```
"wExwM7pR"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.