# To sort the letters in a string alphabetically in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-performance

I am currently using this method to sort letters in a string alphabetically in PostgreSQL. Are there any other efficient methods?

```
select string_agg(c, '') as s
from   (select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('ijsAafhareDbv', '')) as c 
        order  by c) as t; 

       s   
 --------------
 ADaabefhijrsv
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty reasonable solution.

Comment: @Gordon : could  there be a method to avoid regexp, since the processing is a bit  slower with it?  Although we don't need to run it everyday,  once in a while it needs to to be applied on huge volume of data. Any procedural (plpgsql) approach /indexing/ using external libraries are also ok if it works well.

Comment: Remember about [`pl/perl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) or [`pl/python`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) or other third-party procedural languages. It could be much faster for such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function implemented in `C` is *substantially* faster than anything we can achieve with `LANGUAGE sql` or `plpgsql`. So [your `plpythonu` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50422700/939860) wins the performance contest by a long shot.

But `plpythonu` is an ***untrusted*** procedural language. It's not installed by default and only superusers can create functions in untrusted languages. You need to be aware of security implications. And untrusted languages are not available at all on most cloud services.
[The current manual (quote from pg 10):](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html)

> PL/Python is only available as an “untrusted” language, meaning it
>   does not offer any way of restricting what users can do in it and is
>   therefore named `plpythonu`. A trusted variant `plpython` might become
>   available in the future if a secure execution mechanism is developed
>   in Python. The writer of a function in untrusted PL/Python must take
>   care that the function cannot be used to do anything unwanted, since
>   it will be able to do anything that could be done by a user logged in
>   as the database administrator. Only superusers can create functions in
>   untrusted languages such as `plpythonu`.

The SQL functions you tested are not well optimized. There are a thousand and one **ways to improve performance**, yet:

#### Demo

> ```
> -- func to create random strings
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_random_string(int)
>   RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(
>    SELECT substr('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', (ceil(random()*62))::int, 1)
>    FROM generate_series(1, $1)
>    ), '')
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
>
> -- test tbl with 100K rows
> CREATE TABLE tbl(str text);
> INSERT INTO tbl
> SELECT f_random_string(15)
> FROM   generate_series(1, 100000) g;
> ```

> ```
> VACUUM ANALYZE tbl;
> ```

> ```
> -- 1: your test function 1 (inefficient)
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort1(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$  -- your test function 1 (very inefficient)
> SELECT string_agg(c, '')
> FROM  (SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, '')) AS c ORDER  BY c) t;
> $func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 2: your test function 2 ( inefficient)
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort2(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> WITH t(s) AS (VALUES ($1))
> SELECT string_agg(substr(t.s, g.g, 1), '' ORDER BY substr(t.s, g.g, 1))
> FROM   t
> CROSS  JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, length(t.s)) g;
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 3: remove pointless CTE from sort2
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort3(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT string_agg(substr($1, g, 1), '' ORDER BY substr($1, g, 1))
> FROM   generate_series(1, length($1)) g;
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 4: use unnest instead of calling substr N times
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort4(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT string_agg(c, '' ORDER BY c)
> FROM   unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 5: ORDER BY in subquery
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort5(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT string_agg(c, '')
> FROM  (
>    SELECT c
>    FROM   unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c
>    ORDER  BY c
>    ) sub
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 6: SRF in SELECT list
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort6(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT string_agg(c, '')
> FROM  (SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c ORDER BY 1) sub
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 7: ARRAY constructor instead of aggregate func
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort7(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1, NULL)) c ORDER BY c), '')
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
>
> -- 8: The same with COLLATE "C"
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort8(text)  RETURNS text AS
> $func$
> SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT unnest(string_to_array($1 COLLATE "C", NULL)) c ORDER BY c), '')
> $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT str, sort1(str), sort2(str), sort3(str), sort4(str), sort5(str), sort6(str), sort7(str), sort8(str) FROM tbl LIMIT 1;  -- result sample
> ```
>
> ```
> str             | sort1           | sort2           | sort3           | sort4           | sort5           | sort6           | sort7           | sort8          
> :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :--------------
> tUkmori4D1rHhI1 | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DhHiIkmorrtU | 114DHIUhikmorrt
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort1(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.053 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 2742.904 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort2(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.105 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 2579.397 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort3(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.079 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 2191.228 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort4(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.075 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 2194.780 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort5(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.083 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 1902.829 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort6(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.075 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 1866.407 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort7(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.067 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 1863.713 ms                                                              |
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT sort8(str) FROM tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                               |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual rows=100000 loops=1) |
> | Planning time: 0.074 ms                                                                  |
> | Execution time: 1569.376 ms                                                              |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=759d13ef0d97a6d4e707368f55196469)*

The last one sorts without `COLLATION` rules, that's strictly by byte values of characters, which is substantially cheaper. But you may or may not *need* the sort order for a different locale.

[The manual about `COLLATION` expressions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS)

Answer (score 4):

I created 3 functions, one using my query, another using Laurenz's query and one more: I created a Python(plpythonu) function for sorting. Finally, I created a table with 100000 rows( I did it from my Mac Laptop for now )
 with each containing a random 15 character string generated using the `random_string` function in this [*Link*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-random-string-thats-suitable-for-a-session-id-in-postgresql)

```
create table t as select random_string(15) as s FROM generate_series(1,100000);
```

Here are the 3 functions.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION sort1(x TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
select string_agg(c, '') as s
from   (select unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, '')) as c 
        order  by c) as t;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;


CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION sort2(x TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
WITH t(s) AS (VALUES ($1))
SELECT string_agg(substr(t.s, g.g, 1), ''
                  ORDER BY substr(t.s, g.g, 1)
                 )
FROM t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, length(t.s)) g;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;


create language plpythonu;
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION pysort(x text)
  RETURNS text
AS $$
  return ''.join(sorted(x))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu IMMUTABLE;
```

These are the results from `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` for all three.

```
knayak=# EXPLAIN ANALYSE select sort1(s)  FROM t;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual time=0.266..7097.740 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.119 ms
 Execution time: 7106.871 ms
(3 rows)

knayak=# EXPLAIN ANALYSE select sort2(s)  FROM t;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual time=0.418..7012.935 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.270 ms
 Execution time: 7021.587 ms
(3 rows)

knayak=# EXPLAIN ANALYSE select pysort(s) FROM t;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..26541.00 rows=100000 width=32) (actual time=0.060..389.729 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.048 ms
 Execution time: 395.760 ms
(3 rows)
```

From this analysis, it turns out - **Python sort** was the fastest and no considerable differences between the first 2. Need to check the performance in real-time for huge tables in our systems though.

Comment: native function - implemented in C language like `sorted` method in from Python library must be most fast code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution without regular expressions, you could use this:

```
WITH t(s) AS (VALUES ('amfjwzeils'))
SELECT string_agg(substr(t.s, g.g, 1), ''
                  ORDER BY substr(t.s, g.g, 1)
                 )
FROM t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1, length(t.s)) g;

 string_agg 
------------
 aefijlmswz
(1 row)
```

I would benchmark which solution is faster.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I did (a sort of ) benchmarking  myself and have posted an answer. Please let me know if I missed or have to modify anything to make it a better comparison.