# How to generate random string for all rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `foo` table and would like to set `bar` column to a random string. I've got the following query:

```sql
update foo
set bar = select string_agg(substring('0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz', round(random() * 30)::integer, 1), '')
          from generate_series(1, 9);
```

But it generates the random string once and reuse it for all rows. How can I make it to generate one random string for each row?

I know I can make it a function like this:

```sql
create function generate_bar() returns text language sql as $$
  select string_agg(substring('0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz', round(random() * 30)::integer, 1), '')
  from generate_series(1, 9)
$$;
```

and then call the function in the update query. But I'd prefer to do it without a function.

Comment: Could you please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-random-string-thats-suitable-for-a-session-id-in-postgresql)

Comment: I'm not following. Why should I refer to the link?

Comment: Because using a custom function is the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: Right. Created as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Postgres optimizer is just too smart and deciding that it can execute the subquery only once for all rows.  Well -- it is really missing something obvious -- the `random()` function makes the subquery *volatile* so this is not appropriate behavior.

One way to get around this is to use a correlated subquery.  Here is an example:

```
update foo
    set bar = array_to_string(array(select string_agg(substring('0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz', round(random() * 30)::integer, 1), '')
                                    from generate_series(1, 9)
                                    where foo.bar is distinct from 'something'
                                   ), '');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1c0887cfc72c96ad353a1dbcd8ea6005) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

**For a random mixed-case numeric-inclusive string containing up to 32 characters use:**

```
UPDATE "foo" SET "bar"= substr(md5(random()::text), 0, XXX);
```

and replace XXX with the length of desired string plus one.
To replace all with length 32 strings, Example:

```
UPDATE "foo" SET "bar"= substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 33);
```

`14235ccd21a408149cfbab0a8db19fb2` might be a value that fills one of the rows. Each row will have a random string but not guaranteed to be unique.

**For generating strings with more than 32 characters**

Just combine the above with a `CONCAT`